# jOOQ code generator does not generate corresponding Index if a UNIQUE index has the function defined on the field

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have a unique index as below to achieve case-insensitive unique constraint on the project name

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS unique_project_name__idx ON project (UPPER(name));
```

It seems that jOOQ code generator does not generate the corresponding constant in **Indexes.java** for such UNIQUE index.

However, it works for the index without UPPER() function

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS unique_project_name__idx ON project (name);
```

```java
// corresponding generation in Indexes.java
public static Index UNIQUE_PROJECT_NAME__IDX = Internal.createIndex("unique_project_name__idx", Project.PROJECT, new OrderField[] { Project.PROJECT.NAME }, true);
```

I use jOOQ *3.13.2* and PostgreSQL *11.2*.

Any idea?

Is **citext** a better way for case-insensitive unique constraint?

Answer (score 4):

This is a missing feature in jOOQ 3.13: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6310

Comment: hey Lukas, do I understand correctly that this not affect actual db performance? What's the impact of missing index in Indexes.java?

Comment: @JakubLicznerski: It's irrelevant. Care to ask a complete question here on Stack Overflow? I'd like to elaborate, perhaps others will also find this useful...

Comment: sure, added this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74164600/jooq-not-generating-index-info-for-postgres-expression-index. I've also added an example index I used, but it might've been generalised better.